# References for Hyperbolic Graph Theory

Tags: graph-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, gromov-hyperbolic-spaces

I'm sorry to disturb you but I really got stuck! I can't find any clear and, somewhat, complete reference for this topic.

I'm looking for a book, or review, or survey or course notes regarding "Hyperbolic Graph Theory": in this way I hope to find some description of general properties or solving techniques for hyperbolic graphs. If search on google, usually I find stuff related to groups or metric spaces or Cayley graphs but this is not what I'm looking for.

I could find only this talk "http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~maslar/talkOW10.pdf" and just this short paper "http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~maslar/OWreport10.pdf"

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Could you clarify what kind of general properties or solving technique are you looking for. Most of the results about hyperbolic Cayley graphs will apply to all graphs. I am not sure you realized this, but all finite graphs are hyperbolic, which means that most combinatorial questions in graph theory are useless in the context of hyperbolic graphs.

Comment: Hi! I know that every finite graph is hyperbolic: indeed, I'm studying infinite hyperbolic graphs. This means that I'm interested more in the geometrical point of view than in the combinatorical one, e.g. concerning questions such as the non-amenability or the behaviour at the (Poisson) boundary of the graph. So far I have dealt mainly with plane hyperbolic graphs, looking for conditions that would force the graph to have bounded face lengths.
Since I've just started facing this topic, I would like to get an overall view about hyperbolic graphs, learning main theorems and definitions.

Comment: Take a look at this paper: http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~itai/stflouraug24.pdf, maybe you can find something useful there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link!!!
Do you also know some reference not focusing on probability? For instance, what about hyperbolic Cayley graphs? (also if I have not considered them in the beginning but I'm desperate) I know it's a much wider subject, but so far I've only found group-theoretic oriented sources and not graph-theoretic ones.

Comment: Paper by Kaimanovich on Poisson boundary of hyperbolic groups (http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9802132.pdf) is mostly non-group theoretic (but heavy on probability!).